# Assigning a new value to a location in a pandas dataframe based on another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (temp_table) that looks like this

```
    0                   1        index  TF      SASA
    6.5227469102210085  222.0    227    False   0.020834600771546936
    3.7721281528298034  223.0    224    False   0.25000423735995525
    5.582663533428659   223.0    225    True    0.8578536501672815
    5.314596793152923   223.0    226    False   0.15678231834437872
    6.107712830515959   223.0    227    False   0.020834600771546936
    3.8005850006883994  224.0    225    False   0.8578536501672815
    5.604560057482539   224.0    226    False   0.15678231834437872
    5.6112774758639885  224.0    227    False   0.020834600771546936
    5.3685540383952395  224.0    228    False   0.3081807524138729
```

And I would like to make column 'TF' be True if index = 225. The ideal output would be

```
    0                   1        index  TF      SASA
    6.5227469102210085  222.0    227    False   0.020834600771546936
    3.7721281528298034  223.0    224    False   0.25000423735995525
    5.582663533428659   223.0    225    True    0.8578536501672815
    5.314596793152923   223.0    226    False   0.15678231834437872
    6.107712830515959   223.0    227    False   0.020834600771546936
    3.8005850006883994  224.0    225    True    0.8578536501672815
    5.604560057482539   224.0    226    False   0.15678231834437872
    5.6112774758639885  224.0    227    False   0.020834600771546936
    5.3685540383952395  224.0    228    False   0.3081807524138729
```

I tried to do this with

```
temp_table.loc[temp_table.index == 225, 'TF'] = True
```

However, the dataframe remained unchanged in the Spyder variable viewer. Is there something that I am doing wrong? Should I try another approach entirely?

Update 1

```
temp_table.columns
Out[98]: Index([0, 1, 'index', 'TF', 'SASA'], dtype='object')

    temp_table['index'] == 225
Out[99]: 
0       False
1       False
3       False
4       False
7       False
8       False
9       False
12      False
13      False
14      False
15      False
16      False
19      False
20      False
21      False
22      False
23      False
24      False
27      False
28      False
29      False
30      False
31      False
32      False
35      False
36      False
37      False
38      False
39      False
40      False

3393    False
3394    False
3395    False
3396    False
3399    False
3400    False
3401    False
3402    False
3405    False
3406    False
3410    False
3411    False
3416    False
3417    False
3426    False
3427    False
3437    False
3438    False
3449    False
3450    False
3458    False
3459    False
3465    False
3466    False
3478    False
3488    False
3489    False
3497    False
3498    False
3504    False
Name: index, Length: 1754, dtype: bool
```

Update 2

```
temp_table['index'].head(10).to_dict()
Out[118]: 
{0: ' 1',
 1: ' 2',
 3: ' 2',
 4: ' 3',
 7: ' 3',
 8: ' 4',
 9: ' 18',
 12: ' 4',
 13: ' 5',
 14: ' 18'}
```

Comment: Because slicing return new Serie or new DataFrame, so you are not updating your dataframe.

Comment: How do I update it exactly? both temp_table.update(temp_table.loc[temp_table.index ==  225, 'TF'] = True) and temp_table = (temp_table.loc[temp_table.index == 225, 'TF'] == True) do not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `temp_table.index` is the index of `temp_table`, it is not the column `index`. Use square bracket

```
temp_table.loc[temp_table['index'].str.strip() == '225', 'TF'] = True

Out[280]:
          0      1  index     TF      SASA
0  6.522747  222.0    227  False  0.020835
1  3.772128  223.0    224  False  0.250004
2  5.582664  223.0    225   True  0.857854
3  5.314597  223.0    226  False  0.156782
4  6.107713  223.0    227  False  0.020835
5  3.800585  224.0    225   True  0.857854
6  5.604560  224.0    226  False  0.156782
7  5.611277  224.0    227  False  0.020835
8  5.368554  224.0    228  False  0.308181
```

Comment: Thank you but this still doesn't update the DataFrame in my variable browser

Comment: could you post the output of `temp_table.columns` and output of `temp_table['index'] == 225`, and output of `temp_table['index'].to_dict()`

Comment: See Update 1. The output for temp_table['index'].to_dict() is too long to include

Comment: how about try this:  `temp_table.loc[temp_table['index'] == '225', 'TF'] = True`

Comment: If that still doesn't work, please post output of only first 10 rows of `temp_table['index']` as follows: `temp_table['index'].head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: @flannel_bioinformatician: your column `index` values is string with blank space. I updated the answer to handle it. Check my updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.TF = (df['index'] == 225)
```

or for more than one value:

```
df.TF = df['index'].apply(lambda x: x in [225,...])
```

Comment: Both of these just makes everything in column 'TF' False

Comment: 225 is int while 225.. is float @flannel_bioinformatician use any value you want

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  temp_table['TF'] = [int(x) == 225 for x in temp_table['index']]
```

Comment: that just makes everything in 'TF' == False

Comment: ye, just compare not 255 but 225.. fix it